# Hide android app Icon and run Activity

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can hide icons from a Menu, but then the app can not run.

Actually, it is a monitoring app. Can anybody help me?

What I want to do is hide the icon when app is installed on device I tried several ways but then app activity not show and I get error:

```
[2012-07-13 12:28:40 - Demo App] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-07-13 12:28:40 - Demo App] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

Comment: Question is not understand by me what you ask.

Comment: i mean i want to hide the icon from android menu when its installed and forever and want to run the activity

Comment: Can you post link to your hack? Or show code that hides?

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: Remove <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  from your activity tag in to hide icon from launcher.

Comment: that code i removed but the prob. is then its not working activity is not showing

Answer (score 0):

why not just use a service? and/or a broadcast receiver?

anyway, so it wont install an icon, use this:
remove this from the intent filter in your manifest.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

you might wanna add a receiver so reboot wont be required.

Comment: but i want it like when its installed no icon will be shown when we install the app its showing i can use service after installing

Comment: remove this inside intent filter in your manifest. <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: but it will not run the activity so without activity or service it will not start the app and i will get this error 

[2012-07-13 12:28:40 - Demo App] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-07-13 12:28:40 - Demo App] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!